# Saved data on JSON file but can not retrieve previous data, only new entries

Tags: ios, json, swift, persistence

I am saving datas on on the json file on the first VC , load the data as well and display it when switching tab. When I kill the app or re run the app again, add new datas to the JSON file, only those new datas are on the JSON file, previous datas are gone(deleted without deleting them manually) and can not be load. How do I save the file so that next time I run the program it will just append to the previous data ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var game : Game?
var weekLeague : [[Game]]? = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        creation()
}

@IBAction func endWLButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if games != nil {
            weekLeague?.append(games!)
        }

        save()
    }

func save(){
        guard let documentDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
        let fileUrl = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("ArrayOfArray.json")
        print(fileUrl)
        let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(weekLeague)

        do {
            try json?.write(to: fileUrl)
                print(json!)
            print(weekLeague)

             print("JSON data was written to teh file successfully!")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

   func ShouldSendGame(game: Game) {
    self.game = game
    games?.append(game)
}

 func creation(){
        let documentsDirectoryPathString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
        let documentsDirectoryPath = NSURL(string: documentsDirectoryPathString)!

        let jsonFilePath = documentsDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("ArrayOfArray.json")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false

        // creating a .json file in the Documents folder
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: jsonFilePath!.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
            let created = fileManager.createFile(atPath: jsonFilePath!.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            if created {
                print("File created ")
            } else {
                print("Couldn't create file for some reason")
            }
        } else {
            print("File already exists")
        }
    }


}



class AllLeagueController : UITableViewController {
    var arrayOfArrayGamesCopy : [[Game]] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.loadData()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }


 func loadData() {
         guard let documentsDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
            let fileUrl = documentsDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("ArrayOfArray.json")

              do{
                  let data = try Data(contentsOf:fileUrl)
                  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                  let jsonData = try decoder.decode([[Game]].self, from: data)
                   arrayOfArrayGamesCopy = jsonData
                    print("Succes")
                print(jsonData.count)
              } catch{
                  print(error)
              }

      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load data here before save ... Also you need to have separate class for saving and loading data .. dot do that in controller .. its against Single Responsibility Principle ...Your load function should return array of [Game] and save data should return success or failure

```
@IBAction func endWLButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //load and set data in games from file ...then append current data and save to file 
        if games != nil {
            weekLeague?.append(games!)
        }

        save()
    }
```